# How to delete all files apart from a set of directories using rm command inlinux?

Tags: linux, delete-file, rm

I want to delete all the files in a folder apart from my LOG directory and my reports directory. Is there a way to do that in Linux terminal using rm command ?

Answer (score 1):

> I want to delete all the files in a folder apart from my LOG directory
>   and my reports directory.

```
rm -rf !(LOG|reports)
```

Make sure that you have `extglob` option enabled:

```
shopt -s extglob
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$rm -rf [your directory path to delete]
```

This command will delete the selected directory and all files and folders in it.